# Upstart job logs not being forwarded by rsyslog - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, rsyslog, upstart

I've got rsyslog set up correctly forwarding all logs on a set of clients to a central server. Things like ssh auth logs etc all work fine and appear in the remote server properly.

The issue is that I have custom upstart jobs for my applications which log to /var/log/upstart/app-name.log and I can't figure out how to get rsyslog to send that stuff to the central server. I've monitored the network traffic and the log lines are not even sent, so it's not a matter of the receiving server having some kind of filter, the client doesn't even try.

Any ideas? I'm using the standard `console log` stanza in upstart (although it's default in modern ubuntu anyway).

My client rsyslog config is vanilla except for:

```
#send to logging server
*.* @10.0.0.74:514
```

which is right at the top of the default file and works for all of the standard log events.

Any thoughts?